# How to use two VLP16 with just one computer at a same time

Tags: ros, vlp16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I have two VPL16 velodyne laser scanners and I connected using a switch to my computer.

I fixed first VPL 16's IP to 192.168.1.201 and second VPL's IP to 192.168.1.202 using Web GUI

and then I ran the velodyne package; roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points2_2.launch

here is the code of VLP16_points2_2.launch

```
<arg name="device_ip" default="192.168.1.201" />
```

```
<arg name="model" value="VLP16"/>

<arg name="device_ip" value="$(arg device_ip)" />

<arg name="pcap" value="$(arg pcap)"/>
```

```
<arg name="calibration" value="$(arg calibration)"/>

<arg name="min_range" value="$(arg min_range)"/>

<arg name="max_range" value="$(arg max_range)"/>
```

```
<arg name="model" value="VLP16"/>

<arg name="device_ip" value="$(arg device_ip)" />

<arg name="pcap" value="$(arg pcap)"/>
```

```
<arg name="calibration" value="$(arg calibration)"/>

<arg name="min_range" value="$(arg min_range)"/>

<arg name="max_range" value="$(arg max_range)"/>
```

However, I just can get only one topic which has combined data of two sensors
Another topic is just empty
Is there anything that I gotta do to get both of data?

Thank you in a advance
I really appreciate your kind

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245218/how-to-use-two-vlp16-with-just-one-computer-at-a-same-time/) by [JeongJae0815](https://answers.ros.org/users/28172/jeongjae0815/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The older velodyne launch scripts did not handle multiple devices cleanly.

There is new code for [issue #108](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/108) which should help.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0